# Find Unique Number from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Please let me know is this a best approach to find unique number from an array?**

```js
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      nums[0] = 0 ^ nums[0];
      /* console.log(nums[0]); */
    } else {
      nums[0] ^= nums[i];
      /* console.log(nums[0]); */
    }

  }
  console.log(nums[0]);
  return nums[0];


};

singleNumber([2, 2, 3, 3, 4]);
```

*If you have any better approach with this, help me out.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in an array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-an-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Maybe this question has to be on Code Review

Comment: It returns `5` with input `[2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4]`  and `2` for  `[2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3]`maybe there's a better method.

Comment: singleNumber([2,2,3,3,4,5]) = 1, is that what you want?

Comment: @icecub did you check the above question carefully? It is not duplicate.

Comment: It has to be only single unique value in array itself.

Answer (score 2):

I've created two functions that return unique numbers from a passed array:

```
var getFirstUniqueNumber = function(nums) {
    var number = null;
    var map = {};
    nums.forEach((val) => {
        if (!map[val] && (number === null)) number = val;
        if (map[val] && (number !== null)) number = null;
        map[val] = true;
    });
    return number;
};

var getLastUniqueNumber = function(nums) {
    var number = null;
    var map = {};
    nums.forEach((val) => {
        if (!map[val]) number = val;
        map[val] = true;
    });
    return number;
};
```

I've created a Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/u88qgxrr/2/

They do what the name says, you probably want the last unique number!